# Populating a drop down list in ruby on rails and saving the result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm fairly new to RoR and having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this.

Basically I want to design a drop down menu that will dynamically populate a drop down of newspapers from the database. Once the paper is selected, I want the user to be able to select an issue category (ex: billing), then a specific issue_type (ex: credit card charge), then the contact type (email or phone) (total of 4 drop downs).

The issue category, issue_type, and contact_type all belong to Issuelog. Each Issuelog should belong to a specific newspaper, as per my model code. I want the user to be able to record the  volume of each kind of contact for each type of issue for each paper, with a very standard set of selections available. The newspaper table will not change after the submission, it will simply create an Issuelog that will correlate to that particular paper (the id created by default - not sure if I need to create any additional keys in this scenario).

Issuelog

```
class Issuelog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :newspaper
  attr_accessible :category, :contact_type, :issue_type
end
```

Newspaper

```
class Newspaper < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issuelogs
  attr_accessible :affiliate_group, :name
end
```

I'm having trouble understanding how I will need to structure this overall to achieve what I want. Will I need to use JavaScript in my view, and does my model design make sense for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you will find this post very helpful. http://pullmonkey.com/2012/08/11/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails-3/

Answer (score 1):

In controller's action

```
@newspapers = Newspaper.find(:all)
```

In model there are many that you can use, You can use something like this.

```
<%=  select("newspaper", "ids", @newspapers.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { :prompt => 'Select' }, :onChange => 'do_your_thing()') %>
```

I hope this helps, But tell if you need any clarification